# Official Android Studio repository?

Tags: android-studio, repository

I found this tutorial for installing Android Studio on Linux: https://linuxhint.com/install_android_studio_ubuntu/

It says:

> In this step, you will need to add the official Android repository to the source list of your system. To do this, enter the following command in the terminal window:
> `$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:maarten-fonville/android-studio`

It declares `maarten-fonville/android-studio` as the "official Android repository".

I couldn't find references to this PPA from Google's official documentation. It's also not mentioned in the Android Studio download page: https://developer.android.com/studio .

I found this page: [https://launchpad.net/~maarten-fonville](https://launchpad.net/%7Emaarten-fonville) , and looking at the description and content, I saw no indication that it belonged to or was affiliated with Google or JetBrains.

I have no reason to believe that there is anything wrong with that PPA; in fact, I even used it successfully in a VM. But I am reluctant to use non-official repositories on my main machine, for security reasons.

How can I verify that this PPA is indeed "official" and approved (and/or monitored?) by either Google or JetBrains?

Answer (score 4):

The repository isn't mentioned as official. You can try other methods to install AS on Linux if you're not sure

Option 1: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-android-studio-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux

Option 2: https://developer.android.com/studio#downloads

AS is free and distributed as an archive...so always chances of multiple copies on the internet. Doesn't necessarily mean they are wrong.